# Could not resolve 'angular2-localstorage' Angular 2 Ionic 2 RC1

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-localstorage

Hello I try to use in my App LocalStorage. I'm installed it. And use. But the compiller Error said:

```
bundle failed: Could not resolve 'angular2-localstorage/WebStorage';
```

I imported it:

```
import { LocalStorage } from "angular2-localstorage/WebStorage";
```

How to fix it?

Comment: May want to show some code, like `app.module.ts` and the component that uses `LocalStorage`

Comment: At final I figure out that I don't need to use angular2-localstorage, because localStorage is already in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

At final I figure out that I don't need to use angular2-localstorage, because localStorage is already in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage